# Trigger just one textInput on an onFocus()

Tags: react-native

My console.log("triggered") each time I focus a  or edit it, no matter the .

How can I isolate my onFocus() ? Thank you.

```
    <TextInput
      placeholder="firstname"
      textContentType="name"
      selectTextOnFocus
      onChangeText={value => this._handleStateEdition("firstname", value)}
    />
    <TextInput
      placeholder="lastname"
      textContentType="familyName"
      selectTextOnFocus
      onFocus={console.log("triggered")}
      onChangeText={value => this._handleStateEdition("lastname", value)}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

They are already isolated but you can add autofocus = false so that your fields won't get focused automatically, moreover there is another method that I have never used is by using refs.

**auto focus method**

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="firstname"
  textContentType="name"
  selectTextOnFocus
  autoFocus={false}
  onChangeText={value => this._handleStateEdition("firstname", value)}
/>
<TextInput
  placeholder="lastname"
  textContentType="familyName"
  selectTextOnFocus
  autoFocus={false}
  onFocus={console.log("triggered")}
  onChangeText={value => this._handleStateEdition("lastname", value)}
/>
```

**By using Refs**

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="firstname"
  textContentType="name"
  selectTextOnFocus
  autoFocus={false}
  ref={r=>this.first = r}
  onChangeText={value => this._handleStateEdition("firstname", value)}
/>
<TextInput
  placeholder="lastname"
  textContentType="familyName"
  selectTextOnFocus
  autoFocus={false}
  onFocus={console.log("triggered")}
  onChangeText={value => this._handleStateEdition("lastname", value)}
  ref={r=>this.last = r}
/>
```

and inside your componentDidMount listen to onFocus events

```
componentDidMount(){
this.first.onFocus = ()=>{
 //some function
}
this.last.onFocus = ()=>{
 //some function
}
}
```